# only send rsyslog's $msg to file?

Tags: rsyslog

I'm using a rsyslog rule to send syslog output from one program elsewhere:

```
:programname, isequal, "myprogram" /var/log/myprogram.log
```

I don't want the rsyslog "header" information (date, hostname, app, pid) to go into the log, I only want the log itself. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The message is defined as %msg% when logging. In the /etc/rsyslog.conf, there is a default configuration that defines the format of a file:

```
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_FileFormat
```

In the rsyslog documentation, [click here to see it](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/templates.html), you can see the format of a message. Make your own template and use it as the format of that specific case:

```
$template myFileFormat,"%msg%\n"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate myFileFormat
```